# $M = \{\alpha \in C(I_{b},\overline{B_{a}(0)}):\alpha(0)=x \}$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis

The following problem has popped up in my study of differential equations.
Consider $C(I_{b},\overline{B_{a}(0)})$, the set of all continuous maps from the compact interval $I_{b} = [-b,b]$ to $\overline{B_{a}(0)}$, the closed ball of radius $a$ centered around $0$. Such maps (i.e. elements of $C$) are obviously bounded, since they are continuous functions on a compact interval.

But consider the subset of $C(I_{b},\overline{B_{a}(0)})$ defined by 
$M = \{\alpha \in C(I_{b},\overline{B_{a}(0)}):\alpha(0)=x \}$.

Is this set closed with respect to the norm defined by
$d(f,g) = \sup_{t \in I_{b}}\|f(t)-g(t)\|$
If so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me write $\mathcal{C} =  C([-b,b],\overline{B}(0,a))$. The evaluation at $0$ function, $\text{ev}_0: \mathcal{C} → \Bbb R$, defined by $\text{ev}_0(\alpha):= \alpha(0)$ is continuous wrt $d$. The set you are looking for is

$$ M = \text{ev}_0{}^{-1}(\{x\}) $$

which is a pre-image of a closed set under a continuous function.

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for!